# Difference between rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have three vectors $(2,-1,0), (1,-1,0), (1,0,1)$ and I want to check for linear independence.
At first I thought I need to put the vectors as rows, and then use Gaussian elimination and see.
Then I thought maybe I need to put them as columns rather than as rows, and use Gaussian elimination and see.
After trying both ways, I got to the conclusion there is no linear dependence between the vectors, but I don't understand exactly what I did.

Comment: The row rank and the column rank of a matrix are equal anyway.

Comment: $\det\pmatrix{ 2 & -1 & 0\\1 &-1 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1 }\ne0$ so they're linearly independent

Comment: Just like @Bernard said, it is all about $A\;\&\; A^{\tau}$ when $A\in M_n(\mathbb F)$ . Otherwise, $r(A)=\min\{m,n\}$ for a full rank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the definition of linear independence:

> A collection of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ of a vector space $V$ over a field $K$ is *linearly independent* if $a_1v_1+a_2v_2+\dots+a_nv_n=0$ implies $a_1=a_2=\dots=a_n=0$, where the $a_i$ are elements of the underlying field $K$.

Assuming that you are working in the space $\mathbb R^3$ over $\mathbb R$, what we need to show is that
$$a_1\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
for real numbers $a_1,a_2,a_3$ implies that $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$. This reduces to a $3\times 3$ system of linear equations by just checking each component. This should be relatively easy and can be done by elementary methods, which I will leave to you.

---

Note: it does not really matter if you consider your vectors as row vectors or column vectors. If you considered them as row vectors, for example, all we need to show is 
$$a_1\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&0\end{bmatrix}+a_2\begin{bmatrix}1&-1&0\end{bmatrix}+a_3\begin{bmatrix}1&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
implies $a_1=a_2=a_3=0$.
But the way to do this is exactly the same: by considering each component! And of course, the equations that we have and the resulting $3\times 3$ linear system are exactly the same; so this is in fact equivalent to the previous view as column vectors.